# How to push code to an AJAX/JS-heavy production site

Tags: javascript, ajax, deployment, continuous-integration, jenkins

We currently use Jenkins to deploy code to our production web server. It zips up all the relevant source and SCP it over to the server and then remotely unpacks it and then restarts apache (we're using APC, so this clears the PHP cache).

The site is heavily AJAX-driven and there are rarely any browser refreshes when users are interacting with the site. When doing this type of code push, I'm concerned about the user not getting the latest changes to the front-end code if the browser does not refresh. So we do this very late in the night to make sure most of our users are off the site.

What are some common techniques to mitigate this issue? This is not sustainable if we ever need to deploy code in the daytime and the users are active on the site. Any other improvements that can be made to this deployment process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound like an issue with the deployment process as it does the application / site.

The first thing to check is the configuration of the web server to ensure that the "Expires" / "Cache-Control" headers are all set to reasonable values, so that you're not setting cache times of 1 year on files that you may be changing weekly (or even daily).

The next thing that could be done from within the application is to include a check in the JavaScript.  Each HTTP response (AJAX or otherwise) could return a custom HTTP header with a version number.  If the application is re-deployed, the application / server must send a new version number in that field.  If the JavaScript detects that the version number has been updated mid-session, it can display a message to the user and/or force a reload of the page.